# Búsqueda por parametros usando variable para capturar información del input

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, angular

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Búsqueda entre dos paramtros con angular 4 y spring Boot.

```js
// en typeScript component

import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  ViewChild
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  ComprobanteService
} from '../../../services/comprobante/comprobante.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-comprobate',
  templateUrl: './comprobante.html',
  styleUrls: ['../css/comprobante.css'],
  providers: [ComprobanteService]
})
export class ComprobantePorIdentificadorAdminComponent implements OnInit {

  listaComprobantes: Array < ComprobanteModel > ;

  constructor(private comprobanteService: ComprobanteService) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  btnBurcar(serie, correlativo): void {
    this.comprobanteService.getBuscarComprobante(serie, correlativo).subscribe(response => {
      this.listaComprobantes = response;
    });

  }


  //// En el modulo Service

  import {
    Injectable
  } from '@angular/core';
  import {
    HttpClient,
    HttpHeaders
  } from '@angular/common/http';

  @Injectable()
  export class ComprobanteService {
    // Guardamos nuestro URL en una variable
    public url = 'localhost:8090/v1/search/comprobante/';


    public getBuscarComprobante(serie: string, correlativo: number): Observable < any[] > {
      return this.http.get < any[] > (this.url + 'serie=?' + serie + '/correlativo?=' + correlativo);
    }
  }
```

```html
<form class="form-inline" novalidate name="emisionelectronicas">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input placeholder="Serie documento" formControlName="serieDocumento" #serie />
    <input placeholder="Serie documento" formControlName="serieDocumento" #correlativo/>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="btnBuscar(serie.value, correlativo.value)"> CONSULTAR COMPROBANTE</button>
  </div>

</form>
<br/>
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table class="table table-responsive">
    <thead class="thead">
      <tr>
        <th>TipoDoc</th>
        <th>Serie</th>
        <th>Correlativo</th>
        <th>Estado</th>
        <th>Accion</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of listaComprobantes">
        <td>{{item.tipoDocumento}}</td>
        <td>{{item.serie}}</td>
        <td>{{item.correlativo}}</td>
        <td>{{item.Estado}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>


<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

">
          {{item.tipoDocumento}}
          {{item.serieDocumento}}
          {{item.correlativoDocumento}}
          {{item.fechaEnvioASunat}}
          {{item.usuarioEmisor}}
          {{item.fechaCreacion}}
          {{item.estado}}
          {{item.totalMontoPagar}}
          {{item.idAdquiriente}}
          {{item.idContribuyente}}
          
            ver

Comment: No tengo claro lo que quieres hacer: ¿filtrar los resultados?

Comment: Lo que quiero hacer es una búsqueda por correlativo y serie. ejemplo Quiero ingresar serio "100" y correlativo "F011" y debo obtener la lista de la boleta con todos los campos. ¿Fui claro?

Comment: La verdad es que no: no sé si el problema lo tienes en hacer la consulta en Hibernate, en mostrar los resultados en Angular, en pasar los datos desde backend a frontend mediante AJAX.... si no especificas qué tienes y qué problema en concreto te has encontrado, no podremos ayudarte

Comment: No tengo problemas con Hibernate,

Comment: No tengo problemas con Hibernate, @RequestMapping(value="/finByCorrelativoAndSerie/correlativoDocumento/serieDocumento", method=RequestMethod.GET)
 public List<EmisionElectronica> getFinBySerieAndCorrelativo(@PathVariable int correlativoDocumento, @PathVariable String serieDocumento) throws Exception{

  return this.emisionElectronicaService.findByCorrelativoAndSerie(correlativoDocumento,serieDocumento);

 }
esta es mi listado por  correlativo y serie. Lo quiero pasar a angular 4   . como el imagen adjunto indica que el listado se ara al ingresar  el correlativo y la serie del documento.

Comment: Tengo problemas en implementar en angular. soy nuevo en esto.   ¿no se si me dejo entender?

Comment: El problema es que aun que tú sepas a que te refieres cuando dices buscar en correlativo y serie nosostros no. Es decir, necesitamos que nos digas exactamente que tiene que hacer o mostrar el código. Buscar por un numero y mostrar los resultados que le devuelva el servicio?. Usar los dos numeros como clave?.

Comment: exacto usar los dos números como clave y obtener la lista.

Comment: Pues faltaría que añadas tu codigo ts donde haces la consulta y el controlador de ese componente a ver que es lo que estás haciendo. Con el HTML solo poco podremos ayudarte.

Comment: Ya lo agregue   service.ts es lo siguiente     public getFindByCorrelativoAndSerie(correlativoDocumento: number, serieDocumento: string): Observable<EmisionElectronicaModel[]>{
    let comprobantes= this.http.get<EmisionElectronicaModel[]>(this.url + '/finByCorrelativoAndSerie' + '/' + correlativoDocumento + '/' + serieDocumento);
     return comprobantes;

   }

Comment: component.ts obtengo el metodo          private loadComprobanteByCorrelativoSerie(correlativoDocumento, serieDocumento){
    this.emisionelectronicaService.getFindByCorrelativoAndSerie( correlativoDocumento.correlativoDocumento, serieDocumento.serieDocumento).subscribe(res =>{
      this.emisionelectronicas = res;
    });